# Changing Player's variable depending on current collision

Tags: godot

I am trying to modify the player's movement speed depending on if they are in a bush or not. This is the gist of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
const Grass = preload("res://World/Grass/Grass.tscn")
onready var grass = Grass.instance()

func move():
    grass = Grass.instance()
    if grass.player_in_grass():
        velocity = move_and_slide(velocity / BUSH_FRICTION_MULTIPLIER)
    else:
        velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)
```

The issue that I am having is that I cannot figure out what the code to check should be. I have tried to create a player detection zone for the grass, switching its value when inside of it:

```
var player = null

func player_is_visible():
    return player != null

func _on_PlayerDetectionZone_body_entered(body):
    player = body

func _on_PlayerDetectionZone_body_exited(body):
    player = null
```

And my Grass.gd looks like this:

```
onready var playerDetectionZone = $PlayerDetectionZone

func player_in_grass():
    if playerDetectionZone.player != null:
        return true
    else:
        return false
```

After all of this, I am hit with the error:

```
Invalid get index 'player' (on base: 'Nil').
```

The error forwards me to 'if playerDetectionZone.player != null:'.

What am I doing wrong? Should I be checking for this/doing this a different, easier way that you know of? All feedback appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Not enough information. At least we need the location where this error occurs. But a full call stack would be better.

Comment: What is your PlayerDetectionZone? I'm assuming it's an Area2D but I'm not really sure.

Comment: @Putnam - It is an Area2D indeed.

Comment: @Strick - It occurs when I try to run the game. It then directs me to:

if playerDetectionZone.player != null:

Telling me that error above.

Comment: The line if playerDetectionZone.player!=null does not appear in the code you posted, which makes it kinda hard to offer a suggestion. I'll take a shot at an answer anyway.

Comment: @Strick Apologies, I updated the original. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum it up:

The error is

> Invalid get index 'player' (on base: 'Nil').

And the line of code where this error occurs is:

```
if playerDetectionZone.player != null:
```

(which is unfortunately not part of the posted code).

This error means that the variable playerDetectionZone has the value null. Assuming the rest of the code is as posted the problem should be located here:

```
onready var playerDetectionZone = $PlayerDetectionZone
```

Something is wrong with the node path ($PlayerDetectionZone). Spelling, capitalisation, maybe wrong position in the tree. Could be a number of things.

Edit: Based on your comment it is probably the wrong position in the tree. The line above only works if the PlayerDecetionZone node is a child of the grass node (the one with grass.gd attached).

Comment: That's what I thought. I'm trying to re-use the same PlayerDetectionZone instance from another location, maybe that's the issue. I'll post with an update.